# Draw circle on surface map Matlab

Tags: matlab, mapping

I have a surface map created from Northing (X), Easting (y), and Elevation (z) data.  I would like to draw a circle around a specific point of a specific radius (say 400 m).  The circle has to show up on the surface map.  Below is my code for creating the surface map.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
% load the map data
x = elevgrid(:,4); % northing
y = elevgrid(:,5); % easting
z = elevgrid(:,3); % elevation
% Put data onto a grid
[qx,qy] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x),max(x)),linspace(min(y),max(y)));
F = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,z);
qz = F(qx,qy);
% plot in matrix form
surf(qx,qy,qz)
```

EDIT
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9EIozHd9086RUdTelNxenBlVmc/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to a text file of sample data - format being longtitude, latitiude, elevation.

Comment: Can u provide example data for `elevgrid`?

Comment: I have added a link to sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with plot3 quite easily. See code below for a modified version of your posted code.

I'm not sure about how your sample data is represented (to avoid problems in the future, please try to brew your question down to just the bare essentials, with inputs included).

```
clear;clc
% create data
xy = -2.5 + 5*gallery('uniformdata',[200 2],0);
x = xy(:,1);
y = xy(:,2);
z = x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2);

% Put data onto a grid
[qx,qy] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x),max(x)),linspace(min(y),max(y)));
F = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,z);
qz = F(qx,qy);
% plot in matrix form
mesh(qx,qy,qz)

% Plot circle
hold on
r = 0.6;
xp = 0.4;
yp = -1.2;
t = linspace(0,2*pi);
Xp = r*sin(t)+xp;
Yp = r*cos(t)+yp;
plot3(Xp,Yp,F(Xp,Yp))
hold off
```

BR Magnus

Comment: This does work, albeit doesn't look 100% professional.  The csv file I attached is 1 m resolution latitude, longtitude, and elevation coorindates.  When I plot circles on the surface map, the line doesn't show up 100% on the surface. It doesn't matter whether I change the line width, shading or turn the grid off. I have attached an example of what I am talking about here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9EIozHd9086WlYtYWxQczlINXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My computer was stolen, so my answer will be delayed a few weeks.. Hope you find some solution, or I can take a look later on. Suggestion: add a constant z value i.e. Plot3(Xp,Yp,F(Xp,Yp)+10) Depending on how smooth your data is, you could also use a non-casual filter (weighted average) on your lifted circle.